# Snap apps not scaling on different DPI monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, snap, wayland

is it possible to make Snap Apps use the Scale of the Display they are displayed on instead of having to manually set "--force-device-scale-factor=x" every time I start them? I have 4 different workplaces (work, my place, my parents place and university) where I use my laptop, each with different DPI Monitors making it impossible to just change the .desktop file in a satisfactory way. It also seems like a problem that is more fitting to 2012 instead of 2022.
What am I missing?

If it is relevant: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland on a Surfacebook 2.
Relevant Resolutions and display sizes I'm using are:
3000x2000@13"
3440x1440@34"
1920x1080@27"x2
1920x1040@40"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling fractional scaling in the settings fixed this for me when working with a 2k and 4k monitor. It takes a bit of playing around though.

Comment: This does indeed work, but I lose a lot of sharpness on the HiDPI screen :(

Comment: Can you explain more? Are you talking about a specific setting of Snap or changing your settings for the screens?